# How to Link Foreign Key with Different Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables: Profile and Transaction

Profile consists of: pID, firstName, lastName, phoneNumb

Transaction consists of: transID, sellerID, buyerID, itemID

My question is:

How to make sure that both *sellerID* and *buyerID* act as a foreign key in reference to profileID in Profile table?

My current code right now:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFILE
( 
pID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
lastName INT(20) NOT NULL , 
phoneNumb INT NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (pID)
)   ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION 
( 
tID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
sellerID INT ,
buyerID INT,
itemID INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (tID),
FOREIGN KEY (sellerID, buyerID) REFERENCES PROFILE(pID),
FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES ITEM (itemID)
)   ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried this and it gave me this kind of error

> 1239 - Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key without name': Key reference and table reference don't match

Thanks.

Comment: Why is your `lastName` field an `INT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about it this way:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION 
( 
    tID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    sellerID INT,
    buyerID INT,
    itemID INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (tID),
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (sellerID) REFERENCES PROFILE(pID)
    CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (buyerID) REFERENCES PROFILE(pID)
    CONSTRAINT itemKey FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES ITEM (itemID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This assumes that a table called `ITEM` exists which has a primary key called `itemID`.  Your original problem mentioned only two tables.  If `ITEM` does not exist, then either create it or remove the foreign key constraint from `TRANSACTION`.

Comment: I'm going to try this first, then I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hi Tim, it works now. Thank you. However, I also want to know what really happen. Does it work because I add the word CONSTRAINT fk1 and fk2?

Comment: You need to add separate foreign keys one at a time.

Comment: @MasAdam, adding to Tim's answer, I could create a new table `TRANSACTION_ITEM` that would be a many-to-many relationship to `TRANSACTION` and `ITEM`. With the current table, you can only sell one item per transaction, but having another table will allow multiple items per transaction.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah.. I see. So what is the "CONSTRAINT fk1" and "CONSTRAINT fk2" really do then? I'm still learning all these stuff, sorry.

Comment: @JRLambert thanks for the input, I will consider that.

Comment: Your original syntax `FOREIGN KEY (sellerID, buyerID)` was saying that you wanted a composite foreign key, but you only gave one column in the other table.  You really wanted two separate foreign keys for `sellerID` and `buyerID`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I understand that, but what I still dont understand is the additional syntax `CONSTRAINT fk1` and `CONSTRAINT fk2`. Can I just simply write `FOREIGN KEY (sellerID) REFERENCES PROFILE(pID)` instead?

Comment: Yes you can write this.  The syntax I gave names the foreign constraints, but is not required.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you!