# MySQL Using Same Foreign key for two different table columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I found this thread similar to my query:
[How to Link Foreign Key with Different Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336953/how-to-link-foreign-key-with-different-name)

But unfortunately the answer to the question above doesn't resolve my problem as on my example tables, it doesn't create any primary key, all foreign keys only.

Here is the query for the table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ref_data(
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ref_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ref_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ref_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT FK_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES client (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ref_id FOREIGN KEY(ref_id) REFERENCES client (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ref_name FOREIGN KEY(ref_name) REFERENCES client (firstname)
);
```

I get the following error:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Here I am using `user_id` twice, with the first as `user_id` and second as `ref_id`. I'm also using firstname as `ref_name`.

This is the client table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You can run `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` after getting that error for more information.

Comment: I run it shows following: 
=====================================
2017-07-13 ...

Comment: To be sure, that was checked immediately after the foreign key error?

Comment: yes exactly after the foreign key error.

Comment: Can you try by removing the `CONSTRAINT FK_*` portions and see if still errors?

Comment: I did that at the 1st place, not working still & Showing same status

Comment: Server type is MariaDB here.

Comment: That should be ok. Can you add the client table definition too?  That way I can try the same here.

Comment: Added client table

Comment: Does the client table create correctly?  There is a stray comma at the end of the password definition.  The create failed for me until I removed that comma.

Comment: Sorry the typo yes client table is created successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, when trying to create the ref_data table, after the foreign key error, I see this:

> LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> ------------------------ 2017-07-13 01:07:00 37ec Error in foreign key constraint of table `ref_data`:
>
> FOREIGN KEY(ref_name) REFERENCES client (firstname) ):
>
> Cannot find an index in the
>   referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first
>   columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not
>   match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and
>   SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns
>   in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition. Create  table '`test`.`ref_data`'
>   with foreign key constraint failed. **There is no index in the
>   referenced table where the referenced columns appear** as the first
>   columns near ' FOREIGN KEY(ref_name) REFERENCES client (firstname) )'.

What that error is basically saying: (in the bold text)

> There is no index on 'firstname' for the 'client' table  (the portion **after the REFERENCES clause** of the FOREIGN KEY

But it's a simple fix. Run this SQL on the **client** table:

```
ALTER TABLE `client` ADD INDEX(`firstname`);
```

... and then run the ref_data table SQL again.

Comment: It just worked! Thank you so much for teaching me a new lesson.