# Error 1005: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database from an EER diagram using forward engineer.  I keep getting the error:

> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `appdev`.`order` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is  incorrectly formed")

SQL Code:

```
 -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `appdev`.`Order`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appdev`.`Order` (
          `receiptno` INT NOT NULL,
          `pono` INT NOT NULL,
          `customer` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`receiptno`, `pono`),
          INDEX `fk_Order_Receipt1_idx` (`receiptno` ASC, `pono` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Receipt1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`receiptno` , `pono`)
            REFERENCES `appdev`.`Receipt` (`receiptno` , `pono`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 31 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Show the ddl for the referenced table as well.

Comment: See this too, someone had a similar issue the other day:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071916/7644018